# Update statement not working properly

Tags: iphone, sqlite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to update database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650275/unable-to-update-database)

I asked this question yesterday, however I got no answer so I would like to ask again. My update statement in my code does not seem to be working. I have values in the database, and every time I use the update statement, it does not update the database. I have copied the sqlite database to my device, and I am referencing it's path. Here is the code I use to copy over the database

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
   {

    databaseName = @"databasenew.sql";


   /* copy over to phone code */

    NSString *documentDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,          NSUserDomainMask,YES) objectAtIndex:0]; 
    NSString *sqlFile =[documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"databasenew.sql"];

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:sqlFile]) {
        NSString *bundleSql = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"databasenew" ofType:@"sql"];


NSError *error = nil;
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:bundleSql toPath:sqlFile error:&error];

if (error) {
    NSLog(@"Could not copy json file: %@", error);
}
    else{
    NSLog(@"yea");
       }
    }
     else{

NSLog(@"transfer complete");
     }
     NSString *bundleSql = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"databasenew" ofType:@"sql"];


      databasePath = bundleSql;


    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
   }
```

Here is my code that I use to update the database, however although it confirms it has carried out the sql command(I have had NSLogs inside the if statement you will see below) it does not update the database.

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *) namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
 attributes: (NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{

  if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Message"])
   {
NSLog(soapResults);  
NSString *convertString = soapResults;
check = [convertString intValue];
NSLog(@"user is");
NSLog(user);
if(check > 0){

    databaseName = @"databasenew.sql";
    NSString *bundleSql = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"databasenew" ofType:@"sql"];
    databasePath = bundleSql;

    sqlite3 *database;

    if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
        const char *sqlStatement = "UPDATE people set user = 'munch'";
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            NSLog(@"success");
            NSLog(soapResults);
            BOOL success = sqlite3_step(compiledStatement);
            if (success != SQLITE_DONE) {
                BOOL myBool=YES; 
                NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"My Bool value : %d",success]); 

            } 
        }else{
            NSLog(@"the fail ispreparing something");

            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating update statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        }


        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);

    }else{
        NSLog(@"fail");
    }

    sqlite3_close(database);
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", check];
    NSLog(string);
    NSLog(@"lolololol"); 
    check = 0;
    [self Bootup];

}else{
         UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Problem!" message:@"Incorrect Username or Password"
                                                       delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
     }
    //  gotoContent = checkConfirm;
    }



   if( [elementName isEqualToString:@"ValidateUserResponse"])
  {
if(!soapResults)
{
    soapResults = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    NSLog(soapResults);
    NSLog(@"above is soap validate user");
}

recordResults = TRUE;
  }
```

For example, this code confirms the update, but the update does not actually happen

```
 if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
    const char *sqlStatement = "UPDATE people set user = 'munch'";
    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"success");
        NSLog(soapResults);
        BOOL success = sqlite3_step(compiledStatement);
        if (success != SQLITE_DONE) {
            BOOL myBool=YES; 
            NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"My Bool value : %d",success]); 

        }
```